# google spreadsheet reading script in python not running from cron schedule but working when i am running it shell command

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am reading data from Google spreadsheet by using python script, the script is working fine when I am running using the shell command but it has not worked when i scheduled it on cron.

so far in check list that i have done

1. file name and location related  no issue available
2. by using `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON` this command i have seen that schedule is fired on time
3. I have added my script method in a different script which is running fine from cron but still that method not worked in times of cron running

cron statement

```
/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python_3.5/bin/python /location/script_name.py
```

Is there any other way to check this why it is not working from cron schedule but working fine from shell command.

Comment: check that the user under which your crontab runs has permission to the file and folder that is related to your script. One way is to run check using sudo  `sudo -u <the user> <the cron job>`

Comment: @AdityaSantoso i have added this method which script already run fine from cron schedule so i think there is no opportunity  related to permission

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the `cron` statement. Add the following to the end `... your script.py >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`. Check after fired by cron if you get any output in `/tmp/cron.log`.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin: Feel free to write the answer yourself to show your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the suggestion from @stovfl i added `>> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1` this line

```
/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python_3.5/bin/python /location/script_name.py  >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

with my cron statement and check the log file and i found i have not used explict path for authentication json file though it is inside project folder so times of shell command it it was working fine. used code just like below

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('file_name.json')
```

and therefore when cron fired the scrip it failed to get the authetication file location and not ran.
then i changed like below

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('location_of_file/file_name.json')
```

now it works like a charm from cron and shell command